# Is it possible to add an App from the SharePoint Online store to a site with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

Is it possible to install an app, that is on the SharePoint Online app store, on a SharePoint site using PowerShell?

If so how is this done?

I had a look at the documentation and found that the only example that Microsoft give is done by importing the app, not deploying it from the store. This can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spapp?view=sharepoint-ps)